# AttributeError: module 'scipy.signal' has no attribute 'special' in python for ploting an parabolic signal

Tags: python, image-processing, graph, scipy, signal-processing

**I want to get the parabolic signal using scipy in python but i am getting error**

> AttributeError: module 'scipy.signal' has no attribute 'special'

#Unit Parabolic Signal

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Unit Parabolic Signal')
plt.xlabel('Sample') 
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
t = signal.special.pbdv(0, 10)
plt.stem(t)
plt.show()
```

**this is the code for python i want to use only an scipy library how can i get signal like this shown in below **

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to import `special` specifically. You don't seem to have imported it.

For example, if I run:

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import signal
from scipy import special

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Unit Parabolic Signal')
plt.xlabel('Sample') 
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
t = special.pbdv(0, 10)
plt.stem(t)
plt.show()
```

I do, in fact, get a plot produced; though, not exactly the one you showed.